# Htaccess url redirect 301 with special characters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, special-characters, redirect

I would to make a special 301 redirection through my htaccess file.
I am a total noob concerning regexp and 301 redirection.

I would like to redirect(301) this url :

http://www.legipermis.com/stages-points/&quot;&gt;http://www.legipermis.com/stages-points/&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt; 
(yes yes it's in the index of google, )
to
http://www.legipermis.com/stages-points/

please consider the fact that i am not an expert about 301 redirections and regexps.
No 301 redirect generator works properly for such a strange URL (which triggers content duplication corrected anyway with canonical tag).

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/stages-points/&quot;&gt;http://www.legipermis.com/([^/]+)/&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt$ /$1
```

or this :

```
RedirectPermanent /stages-points/&quot;&gt;http://www.legipermis.com/stages-points/&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt http://www.legipermis.com/stages-points/
```